# How to send value from jquery to java class in system.out.print?

Tags: java, jquery

**this is my code in html file:**

```
<form name="f" action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
<input class="btn" type="button" onclick="submitForm()" value="ورود" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" disabled="disabled"/>

<input type="text" id="browser_version" name="browser_version" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="browser_type" name="browser_type"/>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {

        var browser_version = $("#browser_version").val();
        var browser_type = $("#browser_type").val();

         alert(" browser_version   :    " + browser_version);
         alert(" browser_type   :    " + browser_type);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "j_spring_security_check",
            data:'browser_version=' +encodeURIComponent(browser_version) &'browser_type=' + encodeURIComponent(browser_type),
            dataType: "json"
        }); 
    });
</script>
</form>
```

**i used ajax jquery in this code. how to show 2 values in to java class for insert to file. ( For Example : System.out.println(browser_version) or (browser_type) )**

**If possible with an example**

Comment: Store the values in session variables

Comment: @Cassian How to Store the values in session?

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jsp-form-session.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a Webapplication which is capable of receiving and processing your ajax request. Most likely you want to use a web framwork like [Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides) or [Restlet](http://restlet.com/).